# React-native open google maps with specific address on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

So I want to open the Google Maps app with specific address from my react- native App but all modules I found required to know the exact latitude and longitude of the address which I don't know I just want the app itself to find them by the address that is given to it.

What could be the best way to do it? Is there like some specific url that I can use?

Answer (score 6):

You Can use Linking Api to do that

```
Linking.openURL('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=centurylink+field');
```

just change query value to what you want

Comment: According to this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html I can use it only if I eject my project and I don't want to do that at the moment. Is there other option?

Comment: I'm using it and I'm not ejecting. However, you may get rejected from the iOS App Store for assuming everyone wants to use Google Maps. I did.


Currently looking for a better solution that switching between maps.apple.com and maps.google.com. For navigation, `maps://?daddr=${destinationAddress}` seems to work on iOS. On Google `geo:`, does not seem to handle navigation, only mapping.